# Finding the new basis for a diagonalized quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given the quadratic form $$A(x,x) = 2x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2-2xy-4xz$$ and been asked to diagonalize it, find the change of basis matrix, and find the new basis in which A is diagonalized.

I found the diagonalized version of A to be $$2\xi_1^2-\frac{1}{2}\xi_2^2-2\xi_3^2$$ where $\xi_1 = x-\frac{y}{2}-z$,$\xi_2=y$,$\xi_3=\frac{y}{2}+z$.  I was then able to calculate the change of basis matrix $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 &-1\\0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

This leads to my question.  How do I find the new basis?  Do I just perform Gaussian elimination on the diagonalized version of A?  So the new basis would just be the stardard basis $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The change of basis matrix is supposed to be orthogonal, right? In other words we should have $B^{-1}=B^T$. I don't think this holds for your matrix?

Comment: I calculated the matrix such that $B*A = D$, where $D$ is the diagonalized version of A.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: The quadratic form is calculated as $(x,y,z)A(x,y,z)^T$, so if you rewrite $(x,y,z)=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)P$ for some change of matrix $B$, the quadratic form becomes $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)BAB^T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)^T$. So IMHO you should try and find $B$ such that $BAB^T=D$. This can be always achieved with an orthogonal $B$. May be your task is more relaxed. In that case I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the answer. Try rearranging your expressions to obtain $x$, $y$ and $z$ in terms of the $\xi_i$'s. This will give you your new basis. For example, say you found that;

$x = \xi_1 - 2\xi_2 + \xi_3$,

then your new basis vector would be $(\begin{array}{c}1, & -2, & 1\end{array})$.